# how to work out what Visual studio 2010 asp/silverlight project using .net framework 3.5 dependancies are missing

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, deployment

I have a Silverlight site hosted in an asp page, it has been developed using vs2010 using .net 3.5 framework and silverlight 4.  It all works on my dev box.  However when I publish the site and get it deployed I get the error:

Could not load file or assembly 'Moe.Tactical.Ttas.Web' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:** System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Moe.Tactical.Ttas.Web' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

I have checked that the ISS asp setting are using 2.0.50727, and that all my references are using that runtime also. 
I am not sure what to do to work out what the missing dependencies are at this point (I don't have access to the deployment box, I will have to go and sit with a system admin).

Comment: I have successfully deployed it onto another developers machine without a hitch... so I can only think that there is some hidden dependency on the .net 4 framework somewhere... I guess all I can do at this point is build up a machine from scratch and deploy onto that

Comment: have installed it on yet another machine that does not have .net 4... still works, so there is something about our "test" environment that causes it to fail.

Comment: See my answer on **[System.BadImageFormatException: Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61336306/system-badimageformatexception-reference-assemblies-should-not-be-loaded-for-ex/61702386#61702386)**.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a case of the GAC, and nothing to do with Silverlight/VS 2010/whatever.

Basically that assembly lives in the GAC of your dev box, but now on your production box, and the DLL is not included in your build.

Comment: There are two projects in my solution that are not silverlight, and both of those dll's are included in my published bin folder... so it seems to be included in my build.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually exactly the opposite of 'TheGeekYouNeed's suggestion ... the system administrator had not followed my instructions, and had included a couple of extra assemblies in my bin folder, lol.

So interestingly it was complaining about having an extra file! (well actually an extra file that was probably a .net 4 one)